# Running apache php processes as authenticated user

Tags: php, apache, ldap, suexec

Is there a way to have php processes run via apache run as the user that is authenticated via ldap?

We are currently running ubuntu machines on our intranet that allow users ssh access and also running web servers with our internal production website as well as a development web site for every user.  All of the directories for our production website are set to 0750 with the group being an ldap group and the www-data user belonging to every ldap group.  Each of our ~100 users belongs to a certain set of the ldap groups, so when logging in via ssh they only have read access to the files/directories for their appropriate ldap groups.  We also use our ldap groups to control r/w access to our svn repository.

We intend to move the user development directories to separate virtual hosts run as the user who owns the directory using suexec/suphp (not quite sure about this yet, but it appears to be well documented).  However users can also easily add files to the production website.  Our concern is that a user could add a script to the production website which could then read/copy every other script in our production website.  Is it possible to have the php scripts executed via apache run as the authenticated user so that they would be limited in their access in the same way they would be if running the script via command line?

Here is an example directory structure:

Directories:

```
drwxr-x--- 16 admin ldab_a    proj_a
drwxr-x---  1 admin ldap_b    proj_b
drwxr-x---  1 admin ldap_c    proj_c
drwxr-x---  3 admin ldap_d    proj_d
```

Users:   Groups Memberships

```
jane     (ldap_a,ldap_c)
tom      (ldab_b,ldap_c)
www-data (ldap_a,ldap_b,ldap_c,ldap_d)
```

And our desired structure:

[image]

Comment: Technically this is possible. However I have problems to follow your outline, so if you could make this a bit more concrete, e.g. with a nice graphical representation added to your question, this should be easy to answer.

Comment: Sorry that my question wasn't as clear as possible.  I hope this helps, please let me know if there's anything else that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look into this project: [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/)

From their site it says:

> suPHP is a tool for executing PHP scripts with the permissions of their owners. It consists of an Apache module (mod_suphp) and a setuid root binary (suphp) that is called by the Apache module to change the uid of the process executing the PHP interpreter.

I hope that helps!